# .NET MVC Error 500 when publishing to production server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dev-to-production

My MVC website is working perfectly on my debug machine when I press F5 in Visual Web Developper Express 2010. I've publish it a couple of time without problem but I did a lot of change lately and my latest publish didn't work as expected.

In fact, the publish works perfectly and no special message are shown. But the problem is that when I connect to the adress, I get an error 500. I google that and add the required web.config info so I get the detailed info.

Here is the information I get:

> HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
>
> The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has
>   occurred.
>
> Module: AspNetInitializationExceptionModule
>
> Notification: BeginRequest
>
> Handler: ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0
>
> Error Code : 0x00000000

Can anyone point me in the right direction to debug this? I can give you more information about my application if necessary!

Thanks!

Comment: Which IIS version are you using?

Comment: I'm using arvixe.com and as I can see in the detailed error page, it's IIS 7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok I found this myself with the help of the helpdesk and google.

1. Helpdesk send me to a [link](http://blog.arvixe.com/how-to-get-more-detailed-errors-in-iis/) on how to show more error on the website.
2. Then I saw my error was "Access to the path XXXX is denied". This was related to the [ClientDependency framework](http://clientdependency.codeplex.com/) and was trying to access a path that doesnt exist on the server
3. I discovered on google that this path was specified in the web.config so I change the path.
4. Wasn't working more so I went on the server and changed the permission on this folder
5. It worked.

Hope this might help someone one day!

Comment: I need to wait at least 2 days (website policy) to wait if anyone comes up with a better answer :)